# Whats the point of separate Getter and Setter methods in Java?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm fairly new to Java -- can someone please give an applicable reasoning for what the Getter and Setter methods's purposes are respectively?

Doesn't it seem redundant to create **two** different methods in a class to receive data and apply the data? Why aren't they consolidated into **one** method?

Comment: How exactly would you create *one* method, when there are two different operations: one to fetch data and one to set it? What would you pass in as the argument if you just wanted to fetch the existing value?

Comment: couldn't you essentially get the data and store it in a single variable and just return the values of that variable? There seems to be a gap in my understanding... can someone please clarify what i'm not understanding?

Comment: The only point where I see usable to return anything from a getter is implementing [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), but you return the current instance of the class, not the value of the parameter being passed.

Comment: Then how would you set it? I really can't understand what you're proposing. It would help if you'd give two versions of a class, both with a single `int` field called `value`. One version of the class has `getValue` and `setValue` methods, and the other is whatever you're proposing.

Comment: (I don't think this is a duplicate, by the way - the OP isn't talking about encapsulation, but about having one method rather than two...)

Comment: This is really a Object Oriented Programming Question. Best place to start is Understand Encapsulation. Messages versus Data Members and how they should be managed especially within the contexts of aggregation and inheritance.

Comment: @myqyl4: No, I really don't think so. The OP isn't saying "why not just expose the field directly?" - he's saying "Why not have just one method?"

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. A getter can have significantly relaxed implementation to a corresponding setter: the setter may have different access privileges and can prevalidate any of the input data.

This helps achieve much better program stability.

Comment: Interesting, thanks yogi. Is there any documentation I can look at that explains this logic?

Comment: Oops. looks like this is a duplicate. Perhaps the other answers can help. Help the old bear here and accept / upvote ;-)